# Exchange 2010 some users mailboxes have a green arrow

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

when we look at our Exchange Server and all the mailboxes we notice that some users have green arrows pointing right over their icon. This does appear to only be on older users on our system so I just want to see if this means that the users have been migrated - or that it is saying that the mailbox exists on a different exchange server? Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This simply means that a mailbox move request exists for that user.  If you expand "Recipient Configuration" you will see an item called "Move Request".  Click on it to view all the existing move requests and their status.  If they are all successful you can select all and clear them.  That will make the green arrow go away.

Or if you like the EMS:

```
Get-moverequest
```

to view all the move reqests.

```
remove-moverequest <user alias>
```

to clear a specific move request.

```
get-moverequest | remove-moverequest
```

to clear all move requests.

Comment: Ooh I totally forgot about `Get-MoveRequest | Remove-MoveRequest` - much easier. +1

Answer (score 2):

That means the mailbox was moved from one server to another but the move request has yet to be cleared.

Go to  **Move Requests** and right-hand click on each user and choose *Clear Mailbox move request*