# What does this icon mean in the Exchange Management Console?

Tags: exchange-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Exchange 2010 some users mailboxes have a green arrow](https://serverfault.com/questions/256790/exchange-2010-some-users-mailboxes-have-a-green-arrow)

I've never really looked that closely before, but in the Mailbox settings of Exchange 2010 some of the user accounts have different icons:

[image]

What's the difference between having a culturally-sensitive icon of a non-gender specific person and a green arrow?

Comment: I know nothing about Exchange, but is it possible that it's a linked mailbox? (At least, that's what some googling suggests).

Comment: Hey, that's some good thinking. We did deploy a 2nd exchange server a few months ago and moved a bunch of mail accounts over to it (I'm not sure which ones were moved though, so it that could be it)

Comment: *["Each recipient type is represented by a unique icon in the Exchange Management Console.."](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb201680.aspx)*  The green arrow represents a recent move request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The users with Green Arrows have local move requests still in the system.  These move requests have likely succeeded and were not cleared.

See the answer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/256790/exchange-2010-some-users-mailboxes-have-a-green-arrow/256798#256798) to a previous question for how to clear them.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. That question is actually a duplicate of mine, so I'll give you the tick and also close it as a dupe,.

Answer (score 1):

green icons indicate that the mailbox still has a move request assiociated with it. The blue one is a native exchange 2010 mailbox.

Have you recently migrated he green mailboxes from another server?

Comment: Yeah, a couple months ago. I just cleared the move request queue now ;)